# passing control through onclick event of radio button

Tags: html, jsp

Can we make the radio button to act as like a submit button? i.e,. Is it possible to pass the control from one page of JSP or HTML to another page by the onClick or anyother events of radio button like the submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From inside any [HTML DOM event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event) handler of any [HTML input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement) in a [HTML form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/form), the parent [HTML form element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLFormElement) is accessible via the HTML input element's `form` property. The HTML form element has in turn a `submit()` function which triggers the submit.

So, this should do:

```
<form ...>
    <input type="radio" ... onclick="this.form.submit()" />
    ...
</form>
```

The `this` refers the current HTML input element.

The following shorthands are also valid:

```
<form ...>
    <input type="radio" ... onclick="form.submit()" />
    ...
</form>
```

```html
<form ...>
    <input type="radio" ... onclick="submit()" />
    ...
</form>
```

But they may interfere if you've for some reason manually created a JS variable `form` or a JS function `submit()` in the global scope.

Note that this all is basic HTML/JS and have in essence nothing to do with JSP. [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) is merely a HTML (and CSS/JS) code producer.

Comment: can I use onclick="location.href='filename'"; like this. what is the difference between this and ur code?

Comment: My answer sends the form data to the server. Your approach opens only the page without sending any form data to server. Which approach to choose depends on the concrete functional requirements which is nowhere stated in the question. As you stated "like a submit button", I just understood that you've to send form data to the server.

Comment: If you have stated "like a link", then I'd myself have suggested the `location.href` approach, because I will then understand that you just want to navigate. Now, what exactly do you want? Then I'll maybe revise my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by using onclick function of radia button. You do what ever you want in that function...

Comment: Can u please paste some sample coding.